# XAML- The name does not exist in the namespace, even though I can see it in the folder structure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, build-error

I have a WPF application to which I am trying to add the functionality to display PDF files from inside the application. I am trying to use MoonPDF (https://sourceforge.net/projects/moonpdf/) to do this, and I have the following XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="DocumentViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocumentViewer"
    xmlns:mpp="MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <mpp:MoonPdfPanel x:Name="moonPdfPanel" Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageDisplay="ContinuousPages" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/>


    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Menu x:Name="menu" IsMainMenu="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="loadDocument" Header="Load Document" Click="openFileMenuItem_click"></MenuItem>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem x:Name="exit" Header="Exit" Click="exitApplication_click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="browserHost" DockPanel.Dock="Top"   Margin="0,0,0,0">
    </Grid>


  </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

I am currently getting a compile error in Visual Studio 2015 on the line:

```
        <mpp:MoonPdfPanel x:Name="moonPdfPanel" Background="LightGray" ViewType="SinglePage" PageDisplay="ContinuousPages" PageMargin="0,2,4,2" AllowDrop="True"/>
```

The error just highlights the first part of the line: `<mpp:MoonPdfPanel`, and says that:

> The name 'MoonPdfPanel' does not exist in the namespace "MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib".

However, if I browse to the `DocumentViewer` folder, which is the route of my workspace for this application in Windows Explorer, I can see that the Windows Markup File `MoonPdfPanel` does exist in the location:

> DocumentViewer/moonpdf/src/MoonPdfLib

`MoonPdfLib` is the namespace that I have given to `mpp` with the line:

```
<xmlns:mpp="MoonPdfLib;assembly-MoonPdfLib"
```

So surely the name `MoonPdfPanel` does exist in the namespace `MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib`...?

If I try to run my code, I get three errors in the console: the first is the one mentioned above, the second is:

> The type'mpp:MoonPdfPanel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

and the third is:

> The tag 'MoonPdfPanel' does not exist in XML namespace 'MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib'. Line 11 Position 10.

As I mentioned, I have downloaded the source for MoonPDF- I have tried building it, but when I do, I get two errors displayed in the console, both of which say:

> The command "xcopy C:...\libmupdf.dll C:...\MoonPdfLib\bin\Debug\ /Y" exited with code 4

Is the reason that I'm getting the errors in my own application when trying to use MoonPDF due to the fact that I haven't been able to build MoonPDF on its own yet? If so, how would I resolve that error so that I can build MoonPDF, and then use it from within my own application?

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the namespace with clr-namespace (assuming that you already have added the .NET project reference):

```
xmlns:mpp="clr-namespace:MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib"
```

See [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've given that a go, but I still get the error: `The name 'MoonPdfPanel' does not exist in the namespace "MoonPdfLib;assembly=MoonPdfLib".`... any ideas why this is?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version that is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/moonpdf/, which says that it was last updated in November 2013... I couldn't find any newer versions anywhere... Although in one of the files in the folder that I've downloaded, it says that it's version 3 (29/06/2007).

Comment: I recommend using the NuGet package - works and builds instantly for me. https://libraries.io/nuget/MoonPdfLib-x86 (Feb. 2015)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give that a go now. I noticed that the link is an `x86` version- my computer is running a 64-bit OS, so presumably I need to download an `x64` version?

Comment: It seems that the Nuget link you provided is linking to the SourceForge page where I downloaded MoonPdf from- so I already have this version...